# What is the text of kiddush for Purim night?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My Otzar Hatiflus siddur only has the Kiddush for Purim day. What is the text of Kiddush for Purim night, and how does one incorporate havdala when Purim begins on Motzai Shabbat?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: What Kiddush does it have for Purim day?

Comment: @AriBrodsky That sounds like a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://apikorsus.blogspot.com/2004/03/purim-was-fun.html, kiddush over wine and whiskey:

> הריני מזמן את פי לקיים מצוות עשה שנאמר על ידי חכמינו זכרונם לברכה (מגילה ז׃):
>   ”מייחיב איניש לבסומי בפוריא עד דלא ידע בין ארור המן לברוך מרדכי“.‏
>
> כוס ישועות אשא ובשם ה׳ אקרא׃
>
> סברי— (לחיים!)‏
>
> בא״י אמ״ה בורא פרי הגפן.‏
>
> בא״י אמ״ה שהכל נהיה בדברו.‏
>
> בא״י אמ״ה אשר קדשנו במצוותיו ורצה שנהיה שיכורים כאבותינו ככתוב בתורתיך (בראשית ט׃כ):
>   ”ויחל נח איש האדמה ויטע כרם׃ וישת מן היין וישכר“,
>   ונאמר (בראשית א׃י): ”וירא ﭏקים כי טוב׃“‏
>
> ﭏקינו וﭏקי אבותינו רצה בשיכורנו, קדשינו במצוותיך ותן חלקינו בתורתיך כאמור (שמות יט׃ו):
>   ”ואתם תהיו לי ממלכת כהנים וגוי קדוש“,
>   כמו שכתוב (ישעיהו כח׃ז):
>   ”כהן ונביא שגו בשכר נבלעו מן היין, תעו מן השכר, שגו בראה“.‏
>
> שמחינו בישועתיך ככתוב (ישעיהו נו׃יב):
>   ”אקחה יין ונסבאה שכר והיה כזה יום מחר גדול יתר מאד“.‏
>
> טהר לבנו לרדף אחרי מצוותיך כאמור (ישעיהו ה:יא):
>   "משכימי בבקר שכר ירדפו".‏
>
> תן יין ושכר לכלם ככתוב (משלי לא:ז):
>   "תנו שכר לאובד ויין למרי נפש. ישתה וישכח רישו ועמלו לא יזכר עוד".‏
>
> זכינו לאכול ולשתות עם דוד עבדיך כאמור (שמואל ב׳ יא:יג):
>   "ויקרא לו דוד, ויאכל לפניו וישת וישכרהו".‏
>
> ותתן לנו ה׳ ﭏקינו באהבה את חג הפורים הזה, זמן שמחתינו מקרא קודש זכר לארור מרדכי וברוך המן.‏
>   כי בנו בחרת ואותנו השקית מכל העמים.‏
>   ופורים קדשך באורה ושמחה וששון ויקר הנחלתנו.‏
>
> ברוך אתה ה׳ מקדש ישראל וסקוטלנד.‏

(This text has been updated in subsequent years, but the newer versions have fallen off the Internet.)

Comment: What's the _shehakol_ for? After saying _hagafen_ on the wine, that covers all beverages!

Answer (score 16):

From [Yalkut Purim Torah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/53068): (I highly advise checking out the rest too; it's really funny.)

[image]

(I might transcribe this at some point.)

There is no havadalah, as we do not make havdalah between when going up in kedushah -- and Purim is certainly on a higher level than Shabbat, as Shabbat we are only commanded to have two *revi'its* of wine, while Purim's obligation is *ad d'lo yada*.

Comment: You should check out Elli Schorr's blog purim365.blogspot.com. He has a full machzor

Comment: Also, I don't buy your svara. There *has* to be havdala because there's no issur melacha on Purim!

Comment: Melacha shmelacha. Wine is what really counts.

Comment: Is there a havdala at the end of Purim, and how would we incorporate it into the Kiddush for Shabbat when Purim ends on Friday afternoon - for in that case we are going down in kedusha?

Comment: @Yitzchak I once heard that Purim is first called Yom Tov, but by the end of the Megillah that title is gone. The Jews refused to accept Purim as a Yom Tov, because then they'd have to make Havdalah. (This comment is completely serious.)

Comment: @AriBrodsky The answer is a little too involved for comments. Please post as a new question :)

Answer (score 10):

From http://ohr.edu/1537:

> וַיְהִי־עֶרֶב וַיְהִי־בֹקֶר, יוֹם הַשִּׁשִּׁי׃
>   וַיְכֻלּוּ הַשָּׁמַיִם מְסַפְּרִים כְּבוֹדוֹ מָלֵא עוֹלָם, מְשָׁרְתָיו שׁוֹאֲלִים זֶה לָזֶה, אַיֵּה שָׂרָה אִשְׁתֶּךָ (נ״א אֶשְׁתְּךָ)  כְּגֶפֶן פֹּרִיָּה,    בְּיַרְכְּתֵי בֵיתֶךָ, וּבִשְׁעָרֶיךָ׃
>   וְהָיָה אִם־שָׁמֹעַ תִּשְׁמְעוּ אֶל־מִצְו‍ֹתַי, אֲשֶׁר אָנֹכִי מְצַוֶּה אֶתְכֶם—‏
>   הַיּוֹם תְּאַמְּצֵנוּ!  (אָמֵן)‏
>   הַיּוֹם תְּבָרְכֵנוּ!   (אָמֵן)‏
>   הַיּוֹם תְּגַדְּלֵנוּ!  (אָמֵן)‏
>   הַיּוֹם תִּדְרְשֵׁנוּ לְטוֹבָה! (אָמֵן)‏
>   הַיּוֹם תִּשְׁמַע שַׁוְעָתֵנוּ! (אָמֵן)‏
>   הַיּוֹם תְּקַבֵּל בְּרַחֲמִים וּבְרָצוֹן אֶת תְּפִלָּתֵנוּ! (אָמֵן)‏
>   הַיּוֹם תִּתְמְכֵנוּ בִּימִין צִדְקָתְךָ צֶדֶק לְעוֹלָם וְתוֹרָתְךָ אֱמֶת, כִּי אַתָּה הוּא יוֹצְרָם, וְאַתָּה יוֹדֵעַ יִצְרָם, כִּי הֵם בָּשָׂר וָדָּם. צְפַרְדֵּעַ. כִּנִּים. עָרוֹב. דֶּבֶר. שְׁחִין, בָּרָד. אַרְבֶּה. חֹשֶׁךְ. מַכַּת בְּכוֹרוֹת.‏
>   רַבִּי יְהוּדָה הָיָה נוֹתֵן בָּהֶם סִמָּנִים:
>   הַצֳּרִי וְהַצִּפֹּרֶן הַחֶלְבְּנָה וְהַלְּבוֹנָה, מִשְׁקַל שִׁבְעִים שִׁבְעִים מָנֶה. מוֹר וּקְצִיעָה שִׁבֹּלֶת נֵרְדְּ וְכַרְכֹּם מִשְׁקַל שִׁשָּׁה מִי יוֹדֵעַ? שִׁשָּׁה אֲנִי יוֹדֵעַ:
>   שִׁשָּׁה סִדְרֵי מִשְׁנָה, חֲמִשָׁה חוּמְשֵׁי תוֹרָה, אַרְבַּע אִמָהוֹת, שְׁלשָׁה אָבוֹת, שְׁנֵי לֻחוֹת הַבְּרִית, אֶחָד אֱ־לֹקֵינוּ שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃ וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ, וְחֹשֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵי תְהוֹם; וְרוּחַ אֱ־לֹקִים מְרַחֶפֶת עַל־פְּנֵי הַמָּיִם׃ וַיֹּאמֶר אֱ־לֹקִים יְהִי אוֹר,
>   וַיְהִי בִּימֵי אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ; הוּא אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ, הַמֹּלֵךְ מֵהֹדּוּ וְעַד־כּוּשׁ; שֶׁבַע וְעֶשְׂרִים וּמֵאָה מְדִינָה׃ בַּיָּמִים, הָהֵם, כְּשֶׁבֶת הַמֶּלֶךְ הַקָּדוֹשׁ.‏
>   אַתָּה בְחַרְתָּנוּ מִכָּל הָעַמִּים, אָהַבְתָּ אוֹתָנוּ וְרָצִיתָ בָּנוּ, וְרוֹמַמְתָּנוּ מִכָּל הַלְּשׁוֹנוֹת, וְקִדַּשְׁתָּנוּ בְּמִצְוֺתֶיךָ, וְקֵרַבְתָּנוּ מַלְכֵּנוּ לַעֲבוֹדָּתֶךָ; וְשִׁמְךָ הַגָּדוֹל וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ, עָלֵינוּ לְשַׁבֵּחַ לַאֲדוֹן הַכֹּל, לָתֵת גְּדֻלָּה לְיוֹצֵר בְּרֵאשִׁית, שֶׁלֹּא עָשָׂנוּ כְּגוֹיֵי הָאֲרָצוֹת, וְלֹא שָׂמָנוּ כְּמִשְׁפְּחוֹת הָאֲדָמָה. שֶׁלֹּא שָׂם חֶלְקֵנוּ כָּהֶם, וגוֹרָלֵנוּ כְּכָל הֲמוֹנָם. שֶׁהֵם מִשְׁתַּחֲוִים לְהֶבֶל וָרִיק, וּמִתְפַּלְּלִים אֶל אֵל לֹא יוֹשִׁיעַ. וַאֲנַחְנוּ כּוֹרְעִים וּמִשְׁתַּחֲוִים וּמוֹדִים לִפְנֵי מֶלֶךְ מַלְכֵי הַמְּלָכִים הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה׳, אֱ־לֹקֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, הַמּוֹצִיא מֵחַבֵרוֹ עָלָיו הָרְאָיָה.‏

Comment: Formatting help would be appreciated.